# Copied file from HDFS don't show in local machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I copied a folder from HDFS to my local machine using the following command:

> hdfs dfs -copyToLocal   hdfs:///user/myname/output-64-32/ 
>   ~/Documents/fromHDFS

But I can not see any file in fromHDFS folder and also when I try to run the command again, it says "File exists".
Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output when you do `ls  ~/Documents/fromHDFS`?

Comment: The problem was related to my connection to cluster!
Now I can see the files. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
rm -r ~/Documents/fromHDFS/*
hdfs dfs -get /user/myname/output-64-32/ ~/Documents/fromHDFS/
```